# Initializating struct error: 'theGrid' being used without being initialized

Tags: c, struct, initialization, opencl

I am trying to create a 3d grid for my OpenCl/GL fluid. The problem Im having is that for some reason the my grid initialization function does not work properly. Here is my *.h, *.c setup and (at the end) call in main:

(grid.h):

```
#if RunGPU 
    #define make_float3(x,y,z) (float3)(x,y,z)
    #define make_int3(i,j,k) (int3)(i,j,k)
#else
    typedef struct i3{
        int i,j,k; 
    } int3;

    typedef struct f3{
        float x,y,z; 
    } float3;

    #define __global 
    #define make_float3(x,y,z) {x , y , z}
    #define make_int3(x,y,z) {x , y ,z}
#endif

typedef struct grid3 * grid3_t; // u,v,w
typedef struct grid  * grid_t;  // p

struct grid3 {
    __global float3* values_;
    __global float * H_;
    __global float * h_;

    int dimx_;
    int dimy_;
    int dimz_; 
} ;

struct grid {
    __global float * values_;

    int dimx_;
    int dimy_;
    int dimz_; 
};
void grid3_init(grid3_t grid,__global float3* vel,__global float* H,__global float *h, int X, int Y, int Z);
```

(grid.c):

```
void grid3_init(grid3_t grid,__global float3* val,__global float* H,__global float *h, int X, int Y, int Z){
    grid->values_ = val;
    grid->H_ = H;
    grid->h_ = h;
    grid->dimx_ = X;
    grid->dimy_ = Y;
    grid->dimz_ = Z;
}
```

In main im initializing my grid like so:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const int size3d = Bx*(By+2)*Bz;
    const int size2d = Bx*Bz;

    float3 * velocities = (float3*)malloc(size3d*sizeof(float3));
    float  * H = (float*)malloc(size2d*sizeof(float));
    float  * h = (float*)malloc(size2d*sizeof(float));

    for(int i = 0; i < size3d; i++){
        float3 tmp = make_float3(0.f,0.f,0.f);
        velocities[i] = tmp;
        if(i < size2d){
            H[i] = 1;
            h[i] = 2;
        }
    }

    grid3_t theGrid;
    grid3_init(theGrid, velocities, H, h, Bx, By, Bz); // <- ERROR OCCURS HERE
}
```

The error im getting is during runtime - **"Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'theGrid' is being used without being initialized"**. But thats precisely the job of grid3_init?

As im trying to write code to work for both Host and GPU I have to sacrifice the use of classes and work strictly with structs - which I have less experience with.

At this point I dont really know what to google either, I appriciate any help i can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct grid3 theGrid;
grid3_init(&theGrid, velocities, H, h, Bx, By, Bz);
```

You need to create `grid3` instance and pass its pointer to `grid3_init`. Your existing code just uses uninitialized pointer.

Comment: This worked! Why did it not work before? I mean I had "typedef struct grid3 * grid3_t;" right? I interpret that as "grit3_t grid == struct grid3 * grid" - wrong?

Comment: You need to have the structure instance, and not just pointer which points to anywhere. `grid3_t theGrid` is pointer and `struct grid3 theGrid` is actual structure instance.